How to get the data of google analytics4 path explore through api, such as the data in the following image
I tried to use ga4's api to set different dimensions and metrics to get the data, but none of them can get the user id and user related access stream data, what should I do to get the data in the image?
Please help me.
Please help me.
I want the user id and related data as in the picture
Get user-related access stream data based on user ids
